# process spawned by subprocess.run only runs single threaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, posix

I'm doing an assignment that requires me to investigate how using threads speeds up different tasks.

I have a C program that takes 3 command line arguments: the problem size, amount of threads to use and path to the data to process. I am starting this program using subprocess.run (after generating test data). However, the program seems to run sequentially (when I run htop, I only see one processor working). Running this code from command line results in the expected amount of processors working at max capacity. What am I doing wrong?

Python script below:

```py
from subprocess import run
import os
from random import random

program_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "out")

for problem_size in [3, 10, 100, 1000, 5000]:
    file_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "problem_s_{}".format(problem_size))
    arr = [str(random() * 10) for _ in range(problem_size * problem_size)]
    with open("{}.txt".format(file_name), 'w') as f:
        f.write(' '.join(arr))

    print("finished writing data")
    for threads_to_use in range(1, 10):
        c_program = run(map(str, [program_name, threads_to_use, problem_size, file_name]), capture_output=True)
        print("DONE problem size: {}, threads: {}".format(problem_size, threads_to_use))
```

Comment: `subprocess.run`, itself, has no control over how the OS schedules a task, or how that tasks splits itself off into threads. I'd probably start by looking into whether your command-line environment differs from your process environment -- whether you're in a cgroup or other environment that's adding restrictions, for example.

Comment: That said, using `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.Popen` means you wait for the first process to start before starting another one. That's probably contrary to your intent when you have a `for thread_to_use in range(...)` loop.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is start 10 processes (not 10 threads!), then you might do it like so: `c_programs = [ run(map(str, [program_name, threads_to_use, problem_size, file_name]), capture_output=True) for threads_to_use in range(1, 10) ]`

Comment: Otherwise... you do realize that `range(1,10)` starts at `1`, so the first time you run your program, you're running it with a `1` in the `threads_to_use` parameter (and because you're using `run` instead of `Popen`, no other copies get started until that first one completes)?

Comment: That's about as much as I can offer without a [mre] letting others produce the problem themselves, on their own machines, without needing dependencies (like your `problem_s` program) that nobody but you has.

Comment: Solved was running python script from pycharm and for some reason running it from there kept it single threaded. Running python script from command line worked fine